# CSS background color with many (above 20) steps

Tags: css, background, switch-statement, gradient, percentage

I need my object to have a different background color depending on a certain value. In particular, it is a percentage bar with, theoretically, a 100 different background colors (disregarding the nonexistent color when it's empty). The width of the bar varies from 1 to 100%, naturally. I was wondering, how could I make all the different shades automatically?

My basic idea is this: If i have a 100px-wide-image, each pixel a different color, I would try to limit the background-width to 1 pixel, use the right offset, and then repeat it. That way, it is one single CSS property, the offset, that would need to be changed via JavaScript, and there would be no need to switch through 100 different classes. Sadly, though, that is not how background-size, background-position and background-repeat work. So my question is this: What possibilities do I have to make it simple and dependent on not more than 3 numeric CSS properties that are linearly dependent on the percentage?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I have had an idea that I tried, and it works.

I created an image in photoshop that is exactly 100 pixels high and 1 pixel wide. Each pixel represents the color for its percentage. So, pixel 0 would be for 1%, and pixel 99 for 100%. I then stretch that image vertically by at least the height of the progress bar. If it is 20px high, I stretch the image by at least the factor 20. The stretching needs to be done using the nearest-neighbor algorithm in order to prevent gradients where there should be none; each pixel simply needs to be stretched vertically by the factor 20, so sharp edges appear every 20 pixels.

That resulting image I use as the background image that is only repeated horizontally. Using the image-position, I set background-position: 0 -[(percentage-1)*20]px and width: [percentage]%. (The part in square brackets is calculated using PHP or JavaScript or whatever). And that's pretty much it. Whenever the percentage changes, I simply need to change these two values, and the background adapts automatically, regardless of its colors.

Comment: is it something like Bootstrap's Progress Bar that you want? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#progress

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you! Except, with slightly more than 4 different versions. If it were just four, that would be an excellent approach. Although maybe I could just automatically generate all 100 elements with PHP… Either way, I will think about it, thank yo very much!

Comment: Yeah, you can add as many colours as you like in your css - just copy the way Bootstrap implements them - I think they have a slight gradient on each colour but you obviously don't have to use that.

Comment: Ah, I now see that it is class-dependent, rather than width-dependent, which, I'm afraid, is the exact thing I was trying to avoid; it does not change the color automatically when the percentage changes.

Comment: instead of creating the image in photoshop you could use a background-image gradient in css3 and specify the different colors at each color stop, then use the same css for repeating the background and determining the size

Comment: I could indeed, provided it is a gradient. If it's not, I could still use the image.

Answer (score 0):

How different do your colors need to be? In theory you could have 100 different colors based on the alpha value, specified by opacity or background-color. Then you could just change the alpha to match the percentage of the bar using an html5 data-property. say you did something like this:

```
<div class="progress" data-percentage="<?php echo $percentage; ?>"></div>

.progress {
    background-color: blue;
}

jquery:
$function() {
 $('.progress').css('opacity', $(this).data('percentage'));
}
```

Comment: That would require that it be a gradient from one color to another. However, sadly, that's not the case. In principle, I simply need to repeat a one-pixel-wide portion of a background image, but be able to move that one-pixel-mask to the left or right.